# Delta Lake MERGE / UPDATE rewriting data even when condition is not met

Tags: sql, databricks, delta-lake

I'm trying to reduce unnecessary writing of data and only write to the delta lake under a specific condition. Why do these statements always rewrite the data?

```
%sql
MERGE INTO tblTest as target
USING temp_Source as source
ON target.ID = source.ID
WHEN MATCHED AND 1 = 0
THEN UPDATE SET *
```

or this

```
deltaTable.alias("target").merge(
  source = dfSource.alias("source"),
  condition = expr("source.ID = target.ID")) \
.whenMatchedUpdateAll('1 = 0') \
.execute()
```

I'm expecting that only table metadata would be updated and no data from the source would be written to the target.

Comment: what Delta version (if OSS), or Databricks Runtime version?

Answer (score 2):

That's a known behavior of the Delta - it rewrites every file that hase matching record in the `ON` clause, regardless of the condition for `WHEN MATCHED` / `WHEN NOT MATCHED`.  If you want to avoid this, move your condition into the `ON` clause.

Comment: This seems to apply to inserts as well. I.e., `dt.alias('delta_table').merge(df.alias('df'), 'delta_table.id = df.id').whenNotMatchedInsertAll()` will create a new file, even if no insert happens (because the merge condition is matched). Is there a way to prevent this, i.e. only create a new file when there is an actual insert (`id` not found in the delta table)? You can't simply invert the boolean condition, since `whenMatchedInsert` does not exist in the API.

Comment: I'm not sure about API, I usually use SQL for merge...

Comment: Thank you, so via SQL it should work? I guess `WHEN NOT MATCHED` is available in SQL?
I've created a separate question for the python case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66527457/delta-lake-insert-rewrites-data-even-if-insert-condition-is-not-met

Comment: Yes, `WHEN NOT MATCHED` is available in SQL